# Dynamic focus area for android camera

Tags: android, camera, autofocus

I am building an android camera app (not using camera2 api) to take close-range pictures of some objects in the outdoor conditions. The pictures needs to be taken in burst mode i.e. once activated the camera will take say 5 pics continuously and all the pics needs to be well focussed. The user may be moving the camera while taking pics and user will not be able to manually choose the point of focus. The objects are dark in color and sometimes the camera is being over-exposed by bright objects in the camera view.
I know how to set focus area as camera parameters but the position of focus area has to be changed automatically so that its always focussed on the dark regions in the camera view. The position of dark objects is not fixed in camera view and so the app will have to look for dark pixels in every frame before setting focus area.
I am thinking of checking for dark regions in the `onPreviewFrame()` callback but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do that. Has anyone done this before who can point me in the right direction? For example is there a project which will make android camera focus on a face always using a face detector? I tried to look on internet but could not find any relevant projects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement touched focus. Domething like this:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

  if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
   float x = event.getX();
      float y = event.getY();
      float touchMajor = event.getTouchMajor();
      float touchMinor = event.getTouchMinor();

      Rect touchRect = new Rect(
        (int)(x - touchMajor/2), 
        (int)(y - touchMinor/2), 
        (int)(x + touchMajor/2), 
        (int)(y + touchMinor/2));
      if (mTouchEventListener != null)
          mTouchEventListener.touchFocus(touchRect, false);
  }
```

where touchFocus looks like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void touchFocus(Rect tfocusRect, boolean useInMid) {

        if (mCamera == null) return;

        try{
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus(); 

         //Convert from View's width and height to +/- 1000
      Rect targetFocusRect = (useInMid || sfv == null) ? new Rect() :
          new Rect(tfocusRect.left * 2000/sfv.getWidth() - 1000,
                tfocusRect.top * 2000/sfv.getHeight() - 1000,
                tfocusRect.right * 2000/sfv.getWidth() - 1000,
                tfocusRect.bottom * 2000/sfv.getHeight() - 1000);

      final List<Camera.Area> focusList = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
      Camera.Area focusArea = new Camera.Area(targetFocusRect, 1000);
      focusList.add(focusArea);
      Parameters para = mCamera.getParameters();
      O.Log.d(TAG,para.getMaxNumFocusAreas() + ";" +  para.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() + " >> " + tfocusRect.toString()); 
      para.setFocusAreas(focusList);
      para.setMeteringAreas(focusList);
          try{
          mCamera.setParameters(para);
          }catch(RuntimeException e){
              O.Log.e(TAG, "setParameters failed", e);
          }
     mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
//   _.setCameraTorch(1);
        }catch (Exception e){
            O.Log.e(TAG, "Touch Focus Camera Error", e);
        }
    }
     private static AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

for new API  read this post http://www.morethantechnical.com/2017/02/28/android-camera2-touch-to-focus/

```
 //Override in your touch-enabled view (this can be differen than the view you use for displaying the cam preview)
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        final int actionMasked = motionEvent.getActionMasked();
        if (actionMasked != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return false;
        }
        if (mManualFocusEngaged) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Manual focus already engaged");
            return true;
        }

        final Rect sensorArraySize = mCameraInfo.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);

        //TODO: here I just flip x,y, but this needs to correspond with the sensor orientation (via SENSOR_ORIENTATION)
        final int y = (int)((motionEvent.getX() / (float)view.getWidth())  * (float)sensorArraySize.height());
        final int x = (int)((motionEvent.getY() / (float)view.getHeight()) * (float)sensorArraySize.width());
        final int halfTouchWidth  = 150; //(int)motionEvent.getTouchMajor(); //TODO: this doesn't represent actual touch size in pixel. Values range in [3, 10]...
        final int halfTouchHeight = 150; //(int)motionEvent.getTouchMinor();
        MeteringRectangle focusAreaTouch = new MeteringRectangle(Math.max(x - halfTouchWidth,  0),
                                                                 Math.max(y - halfTouchHeight, 0),
                                                                 halfTouchWidth  * 2,
                                                                 halfTouchHeight * 2,
                                                                 MeteringRectangle.METERING_WEIGHT_MAX - 1);

        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackHandler = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                mManualFocusEngaged = false;

                if (request.getTag() == "FOCUS_TAG") {
                    //the focus trigger is complete -
                    //resume repeating (preview surface will get frames), clear AF trigger
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, null);
                    mCameraOps.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureFailure failure) {
                super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
                Log.e(TAG, "Manual AF failure: " + failure);
                mManualFocusEngaged = false;
            }
        };

        //first stop the existing repeating request
        mCameraOps.stopRepeating();

        //cancel any existing AF trigger (repeated touches, etc.)
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
        mCameraOps.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallbackHandler, mBackgroundHandler);

        //Now add a new AF trigger with focus region
        if (isMeteringAreaAFSupported()) {
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, new MeteringRectangle[]{focusAreaTouch});
        }
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.setTag("FOCUS_TAG"); //we'll capture this later for resuming the preview

        //then we ask for a single request (not repeating!)
        mCameraOps.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallbackHandler, mBackgroundHandler);
        mManualFocusEngaged = true;

        return true;
    }

    private boolean isMeteringAreaAFSupported() {
        return mCameraInfo.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_MAX_REGIONS_AF) >= 1;
    }
```

Comment: I see there is an ambiguity in the question and so I have edited it. Thanks for reply but I need to set focus automatically and not by user touching on the screen. The camera has to detect the dark region itself and change the focus point.

Comment: you can modify this focus area by yourself

Comment: the area of focus is not important but its position. I need the camera app to choose the point of focus automatically.